# Removing directory with git filter-branch returns "Directory not empty" on non-existing directories

Tags: git

I am trying to remove directory "bob" from the history of a git repository with this command:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -rf bob/' --prune-empty -- --all
```

However I obtain an error after a while:

```
rm: cannot remove directory `bob/some_folder': Directory not empty
```

Where `some_folder` is a directory that does not exist at the HEAD. Why is it happening and how could I correctly remove this directory and its history?

Comment: This seems like it *should* be impossible, since `filter-branch` makes a new temporary directory and does all its action in it, which should keep it all private, which should mean that `rm -rf` can always remove everything.  The implication is that some outside entity is interfering and/or things are not happening in normal causality order, e.g., due to weird networked file systems (such as Dropbox).

Comment: @torek: The command was called on the local disk so I don't think it is a networked file problem. However Sourcetree had the repository open during the call so that could be a possible outside entity that interfered with the files.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, torek was right: an outside entity, in this case Sourcetree, was messing with the files while the command was working. Closing Sourcetree solved the issue.